# Lambda cannot connect to RDS: Task timed out after 60.01 seconds in the same account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

1. My lambda and `RDS` reside in the same account, but in different `VPCs`;
2. I've added all necessary I am permissions to my Lambda to access this `RDS`;
3. The credentials are correct as I could use the exactly same credentials to access/read/write tables in the `RDS` via a `SQL` client from my `MacBook` directly, but just not through this Lambda function;
4. I created a `VPC` peering between my Lambda `VPC` and `RDS` `VPC`;
5. I enabled `DNS` resolution on both `VPCs` and the `VPC` peering connection

The issue still persists, from my Lambda log, it just says:

```
2023-05-18T23:12:09.199Z abcad-cbd-129084-jcdosibn-cdascds Task timed out after 60.03 seconds
```

Here's my `Python` code to access `RDS`:

```
import pgdb

def get_db_conn():
    try:
        return pgdb.connect(host=endpoint, port=8192, database='cool_db', user=token['username'], password=token['password'])
    except Exception as e:
        logger.info("Database connection failed due to {}".format(e))
```

Here's related info re: my RDS VPC:

```
CIDR: 10.0.0.0/16
```

Here's Lambda VPC:

```
CIDR: 10.1.0.0/16
```

I've set up a VPC peering between these two VPCs.

Comment: Can you connect from ec2-instance in the same subnet as the lambda to the rds? Your question lacks any information about your vpc setups, security groups, nat rules, route tables, etc.

Comment: I've just added two VPC CIDR info, will add more info soon.

Comment: What is the configuration of the Inbound rules on the Security Group associated with the Amazon RDS instance?

Comment: Interesting, I didn't find any SG associated with my RDS instance, only the associated VPC has SGs, is that what you are asking for?